# Sharepoint 2007: Insert a list item with hyperlink field via web services

Tags: sharepoint, wss

I need to know how to insert a list item with a hyperlink field using the oob web services.

I already have the code to do the insert, just not sure about the hyperlink.

Here is a standard text field (just part of the code):

```
+ @"<Field Name=""Annotation"">" + this.messageEnvelope.DM.Annotation + "</Field>"
```

Now how can I insert a hyperlink , there is absolutely no documentation on this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint stores its links in this format (note the comma and space between the URL and the description):

> url, description
>   http://example.com, An Example

I'm not sure about the web service, but it should work just the same.

From code, you can use the [SPFieldUrlValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldurlvalue.aspx) class to format this value:

```
SPFieldUrlValue urlVal = new SPFieldUrlValue();
urlVal.Url = "http://example.com";
urlVal.Description = "An Example";
string spUrlFormat = urlVal.ToString();
```

Comment: It worked, but its worth noting that the hyperlink should be a valid link, even during testing , else will produce an object reference not set.

Comment: Used this for a Powershell script.  Thx :D